# Multiple keys to same underlying object in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures

While building virtual network functions (VNF) I came across a situation where I need to store a class or struct object that can be accessed with anyone out of **a set of valid keys** tied to that specific object.

Formally here are the requirements :

1. We need to be able to access a `single-data-blob` using multiple keys. A key can be "empty" or with a valid "name/value".
2. Consider all keys that will be tied to a data, that will identify data. If all are empty then insert data once getting any `<key1, data>` as input.
   If another `key2` comes up for the same data, bind that `key2` with existing `<key1, data>`.

For example, if `person_data` is an object. Then a unique `phone number` or a unique `house number` can be tied as keys. These keys may or may not be member variables of `person-data` class/struct. If they are not member variables then as a programmer we might know the relevant keys already. We should get the `person_data` object with key `phone number` Or `house number`,i.e. we don't need all keys at the same time to retrieve the object.

Is there any existing C++ utility? It seems a very valid use case in general or at least in NFVs (Network function virtualization).

Thanks!

Comment: Are you assuming a single thread or multiple threads?

Comment: Currently our design in a single threaded server but later on this project we must move to multiple threads. Therefore multi-threaded consideration is important too.

Comment: How about creating multiple hashmaps from your key type to a pointer to the object. For example, you can have a hashmap `std::unordered_map<PhoneNumberType, Person*>` and another `std::unordered_map<HouseNumberType, Person*>`. If you really want to use a single hashmap, it is possible too by having a key of the form (FeatureType, Value) where FeatureType is an enum specifying the field you are looking up and Value is the value of that field.

Comment: yes, we can do that. But with multiple hashmaps, we will need to have wrappers and something other data structure to bind those keys too. Because If I want to delete a key -- the desired effect is to delete data for that key. The pointers for the remaining valid keys also need to be cleared. For that something else to find out all the valid keys pointing to the same data.

Comment: @LakshayGarg , thanks, can you elaborate a bit on the `key of the form (FeatureType, Value)` idea ? I am not faily new to the constructs.

Comment: To delete a key, you can just retrieve the object using one key. Once you have the object, create all the possible keys and delete them. Yes, a wrapper containing this logic would be convenient and shouldn't be too hard to implement.

Comment: Your key can be a tuple where the first element specifies the kind of feature you are looking at (phone number or house number) and the second specifies the actual value of that feature. For example, a kry can look like: (PHONE_NUMBER, 646295379); (ADDRESS, "Hogwarts"). The type of this key will be std::pair<FeatureType, std::any>

Comment: Candiate for software engineering? https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b

Comment: @RichardHodges should I move it to soft. StackExchange ?

Comment: @Debashish you might get more traction there

Comment: Another idea: you can store your objects in a mysql like database and create index / apply uniqueness constraints as you like. Insertion, deletion and updation will be pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have your definition of "key" and "data" reversed.

Your example shows that you group two "keys" under a single "data" value. In Computer Science, the value by which you group is called a key. A key can certainly be associated with two data values.

For instance, for a `person_data` object, the fields `house_number` and `phone_number` would be data members. They certainly would not be keys; house numbers are not unique and not everybody has a phone number.

Hence, you can use just a simple `std::vector<person_data>`. If you *do* have a proper key for persons (a value that uniquely identifies each and every person), you might sort by that and have a `std::set<person_data>`.